# Print Array index of object which has an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to print array index of objects, some of which have an array in it.

My array is:

```
"contents": [{
    "title": "Book1",
    "type": "CHECKBOX"
}, {
    "title": "Book2",
    "type": "CHECKBOX"
    "onSelection": [{
        "title" : "Quantity",
        "type" : "TEXT"
    }]
}]
```

So far I tried the following. But `console.log` prints -1 for every iteration. The second object has an array in it. So naturally `console.log` has to print index as 1.

`datalist` is an array which has objects as content

```
datalist.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name.onSelection);
    var keytoFind = name.onSelection;
    var index = Object.keys(datalist).indexOf(keytoFind);
    alert(index);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `datalist.forEach((name, index) => ...`?

Comment: Please read the tag description of `json`. This is not about JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if an object has a value that is an array:

```js
var contents = [{
    "title": "Book1",
    "type": "CHECKBOX"
  },
  {
    "title": "Book2",
    "type": "CHECKBOX",
    "onSelection": [{
      "title": "Quantity",
      "type": "TEXT"
    }, ]
  }
];

contents.forEach((c, index) => {
  if (Object.values(c).some(Array.isArray)) console.log(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is a simple one that iterates through the array and checks if the element has the `onSelection` property. If it does it returns that index. `break`is used to return only the first element that matches the requirement.

```
function getIndexOfItemWithOnSelection(datalist) {

    let index;

    for (let itemIndex in datalist) {
        var item = datalist[itemIndex];
        if (item.onSelection) {
            index = itemIndex;
            break;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```